# object not being pushed into an array in context api

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making a small blog application using React JS. I am using the context api to store the user's responses globally (in InputContext.js), so that it can be used across different components.
What I want to achieve is, when the user inputs a new blog entry on a separate input page (WriteBlogPost.js) display all the blog entries on a separate page (AllBlogs.js). The page changes are being handled with react router. I have a problem where I am unable to add the new blog objects into the array defined in the context api component (allBlogPosts). I am unsure what is causing this, any explanations and guidance towards the right direction would greatly be appreciated.

InputContext.js

```
import React, { useState, createContext, useMemo } from 'react'

//create context
export const InputContext = createContext();

const InputContextProvider = (props) => {
    const [blogPost, setBlogPost] = useState({
        id: '',
        title: '',
        author: '',
        text: ''
    });

    //create an array to push all the blogPosts
    const [allBlogPosts, setAllBlogPosts] = useState([]);
    console.log(allBlogPosts)

    //put value inside useMemo so that the component only rerenders when there is change in the value
    const value = useMemo(() => ({ blogPost, setBlogPost, allBlogPosts, setAllBlogPosts }), [blogPost, allBlogPosts])

    return (
        <InputContext.Provider value={value}>
            {props.children}
        </InputContext.Provider>
    )
}

export default InputContextProvider;
```

WriteBlogPost.js

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from 'react'
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'
import { InputContext } from '../Contexts/InputContext'
import { TextareaAutosize } from '@material-ui/core'
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';

export const WriteBlogPost = () => {
    const [blog, setBlog] = useState({
        id: '',
        title: '',
        author: '',
        text: ''
    });


    const history = useHistory();

    const { setBlogPost } = useContext(InputContext);
    const { allBlogPosts, setAllBlogPosts } = useContext(InputContext)

    const handleBlogPost = () => {
        setAllBlogPosts(setBlogPost(blog))
        history.push("/blogs")
        console.log({ blog })
        console.log({ allBlogPosts })
    }

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        const value = e.target.value
        setBlog({
            ...blog,
            id: uuidv4(),
            [e.target.name]: value
        })
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <label>
                Title:
                <input type="text" onChange={handleChange} value={blog.title} name="title" />
            </label>

            <label>
                Author:
                <input type="text" onChange={handleChange} value={blog.author} name="author" />
            </label>

            <TextareaAutosize aria-label="minimum height" minRows={20} style={{ width: '70%' }} placeholder="Your blog post"
                onChange={handleChange}
                value={blog.text}
                name="text" />
            <div>
                <button onClick={handleBlogPost}>Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

AllBlogs.js(currently unable to map through the array as the array is empty)

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react'
import { InputContext } from '../Contexts/InputContext'

export const AllBlogs = () => {
    const { allBlogPosts } = useContext(InputContext)

    console.log(allBlogPosts)

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>All blogs</h1>
            {allBlogPosts.map((post) =>
                <div>
                    <p>{post.title}</p>
                    <p>{post.author}</p>
                    <p>{post.text}</p>
                </div>

            )}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: the only `push` I can see is `history.push("/blogs")` ... I don't think that's what you mean, is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just update `handleBlogPost`

```
const handleBlogPost = () => {
  setBlogPost(blog);
  setAllBlogPosts([...allBlogPosts, blog]);
  history.push("/blogs");
};
```